# simplify boolean expression: xy + xy'z + x'yz'

Tags: boolean-algebra

As stated in the title, I'm trying to simplify the following expression: $xy + xy'z + x'yz'$ I've only gotten as far as step 3:

$xy + xy'z + x'yz'$

$=x(y+y’z) + x’(yz’)$

$=x(y+y’z)+x(y’+z)$

But I don't know where to go from this step, I'm not sure if I'm allowe to rewrite y'z as y+z' (I'm not even sure if that would help)

Comment: You are *not* allowed to write $yz'$ as $y'+z$. Take $y=1$ and $z=0$ for a counterexample.

Comment: $yz' = (y'+z)'$, but that doesn't look like it helps any.  Try $y + y'z = y + z$

Comment: @DanUznanski Do you know the specific law that your example illustrates? My teacher asks us to put it next to each step.

Comment: I learned it as "absorption" but that's not the term Wikipedia uses for it.  To build it from wikipedia's moves you need distributive + identity + complementation + idempotence + associative, or at least that's what I need for it:  $y + y'z \Rightarrow yz'+yz+y'z \Rightarrow yz' + yz + yz + y'z \Rightarrow y+z$

Comment: @DanUznanski Thanks! I realized that after staring at my teacher's slides for a few minutes but I see it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After figuring things out with a Karnaugh map, we see that splitting up the $xy$ term will be helpful:
\begin{align*}
xy + xy'z + x'yz'
&= xy(1) + xy'z + x'yz' \\
&= xy(z + z') + xy'z + x'yz' \\
&= (xyz + xyz') + xy'z + x'yz' \\
&= (xyz + xy'z) + (xyz' + x'yz') \\
&= xz(y + y') + yz'(x + x') \\
&= xz(1) + yz'(1) \\
&= xz + yz'
\end{align*}

Comment: Oh wow, I don't know why I didn't think of adding in a 1 for the first term.  Thanks so much!